# mongodb use $lte with $indexOfArray

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

for a collection with the model

```
{
    stack: [{mean: 3.5}]
}
```

how can I make this query for the index of the stack array with a mean of less than 4.38?

```
db.stacks.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            index: { $indexOfArray: ['$stack', {mean: { $lte: 4.38 }}] },
        },
    },
]);
```

I am getting this error:
    {

```
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Expression $lte takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.",
    "code" : 16020,
    "codeName" : "Location16020"
}
```

edit:

this doesn't give me an error but doesn't match anything either

```
db.mean.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            size: { $size: '$stack' },
            index: { $indexOfArray: ['$stack', {$lte: ['$mean', 4.38] } ] },
        },
    },
])
```

Comment: Could you explain it bit more ***index of the stack array with a mean of less than x?***

Comment: x is a value that I pass in

Comment: I am trying to find the first index in the stack array that has a mean less than 4.38

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) on every element of `stack` to get boolean values and then run [$indexOfArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/index.html) to get the index of first `true` value. You will get `-1` if there's no matching element, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            index: {
                $indexOfArray: [
                    { $map: { input: "$stack", in: { $lt: [ "$$this.mean", 4.0 ] } } },
                    true
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: This works, I am hoping that someone knows how to pass the filter to $indexOfArray directly. This loops through stack twice and these arrays are going to be very large (maybe 20,000 items)

Comment: @FreakinaBox I think it can only run equality comparison and that's why you need to transform your data

Comment: the docs say you can pass "any valid expression" to the second argument. I think your right but it looks like the docs are wrong. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfArray/

Comment: @FreakinaBox it's not that kind of expression as $expr unfortunately