# $indexOfArray match array element field with value

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a dataset that looks like this

```
{
...
array:[
  {
    field1: 'value1'
  },
  {
    field1: 'value2',
    field2: 'value3'
  }
 ]
...
}
```

I receive 2 strings and depending on some parameters I decide if those strings are a `field1` type or a `field2` type. What I need to do is find the index of those strings in my `array` objects. For example for the string `'value1'` I should get `0` and for the strings `'value2'` and `'value3'` I should get `1`.

If I create my query dynamically and for example I search with `$indexOfArray` for `"$array.field2"` the first occurence will have the index 0, even though it's the second element in `array`, because it's the first one that has the `field2` field. How can I iterate through all of my `array` and find the index of my string?

Comment: Would [includeArrayIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#std-label-unwind-includeArrayIndex) option in `$unwind` be helpful to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found one way to do it thanks to this answer [indexOfArray with map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56066241/9127991)
The idea is to `map` the array so that it contains boolean values and find the `true` one.